# Windows 8.1 poor sound quality

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, bootcamp, windows

I installed Windows 8.1 on my MacBook Pro 13 (2011 late) using Bootcamp and everything seems ok except poor sound quality. It is just so impossible to listen to music. The quality is like a radio or telephone. On the other hand on the Mac OS X the sound is pretty good.

Windows built-in tool for driver updates says that my drivers are up to date...

Is there any suggestions how to fix the sound on the Windows? I just really don't want to switch on Mac OS every time I want to listen to music.

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

The Windows 8.1 and the drivers of bootcamp may interfere with each other.

As Windows 8.1 is not yet officially released I would say that bootcamp isn't yet fully compatible with Windows 8.1

Though this link might help: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1_pr-hardware/audio-lost-after-installing-windows-81-preview-on/7033e0ac-ba83-4395-afdf-9a312dbb3d99

Comment: Downvoter, care to comment?